# Dados vindos do Firebase demoram a terminar o carregamento e atrapalha a ordenação dos objetos

Tags: java, android, loop, firebase-database

Eu estou tentando ordenar um objeto por um valor que vem do Firebase. Eu uso uma classe JsonParcer para listar do banco de dados e de acordo com o ID pegar o campo que preciso no Firebase, que no caso é uma coordenada para que com ela eu calcule a distância. A ordenação será feita por este campo.

**1. Eu chamo o JsonParcer no doInBackground da AnsycTask.**

**2. No onPostExecute eu chamo o Collection.Sort(dados).**

**3. Depois eu adiciono no Adapter para o RecyclerView.**

**PROBLEMA:**
Alguns objetos não terminam de ser carregados na Query do Firebase e quando chegam no OnPostExecute estão com valores nulls ou Zero, atrapalhando a ordenação.

**PRECISO:**
Que a ordenação só seja feita quando todos os objetos sejam preenchidos com os valores do Firebase, para que assim logo depois eu jogue no meu adapter.

Vou jogar as classe abaixo e um exemplo de como vem os dados:

```
public class MototaxiJSONParcer {

    static LatLng currentLocationLatLong;

    public static List<TaxiMototaxiEtc> parseDados(String content, final LatLng coordenadaUsu) {


        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);
            final List<TaxiMototaxiEtc> dadosList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                final JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                final TaxiMototaxiEtc dados = new TaxiMototaxiEtc();


                // Pegar ID, ir no DateTime e buscar Coordenada ------------------------------------
                DatabaseReference raiz = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                Query consultaRealTime;
                consultaRealTime = raiz.child("location/" + jsonObject.getString("id")).limitToLast(1);
                final int finalI = i;
                consultaRealTime.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        LocationData localizacao = new LocationData();
                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            localizacao = childSnapshot.getValue(LocationData.class);
                        }

                        currentLocationLatLong = new LatLng(localizacao.latitude, localizacao.longitude);

                        if (currentLocationLatLong != null) {
                            int distancia = (int) SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(currentLocationLatLong, coordenadaUsu);

                            dados.setDistancia(distancia);

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.i("Local", "The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                    }
                });

                dados.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                dadosList.add(dados);


            } // end For


            return dadosList;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**INTERAÇÃO:**
Confira abaixo a interação dos dados e verifique que alguns dados do Firebase chegam somente depois, o que atrapalha a perfeita ordenação que executo dentro do DoInBackGround:

```
DENTRO DO PARCER: Teones - 3491
DENTRO DO PARCER: Gabriel - 2663
DENTRO DO PARCER: Alisson - 3564
----------------------------------------------------------------
SEM ORDENAR: Teones - 3491
SEM ORDENAR: Gabriel - 2663
SEM ORDENAR: Alisson - 3564
SEM ORDENAR: Carlos Augusto - 0
SEM ORDENAR: Tiago Fontes - 0
SEM ORDENAR: Jaciene - 0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ORDENADO: Carlos Augusto - 0
ORDENADO: Tiago Fontes - 0
ORDENADO: Jaciene - 0
ORDENADO: Gabriel - 2663
ORDENADO: Teones - 3491
ORDENADO: Alisson - 3564

DENTRO DO PARCER: Carlos Augusto - 1918
DENTRO DO PARCER: Tiago Fontes - 4042
DENTRO DO PARCER: Jaciene - 4337802
```

Answer (score 0):

Problemão esse hein, já que o Firebase é async (também), eu só consegui pensar em colocar a query do firebase dentro de um while, e esperar tudo terminar lá, e isso tudo dentro de uma thread, pra não atrapalhar a UI, mas me parece que a sua classe `MototaxiJSONParcer` já é chamada no doInBackground, então você pode tentar assim:

```
AtomicBoolean consultaCompleta = new AtomicBoolean(false);
consultaRealTime.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        LocationData localizacao = new LocationData();
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            localizacao = childSnapshot.getValue(LocationData.class);
        }

        currentLocationLatLong = new LatLng(localizacao.latitude, localizacao.longitude);

        if (currentLocationLatLong != null) {
            int distancia = (int) SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(currentLocationLatLong, coordenadaUsu);
            dados.setDistancia(distancia);
        }
        dados.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));

        consultaCompleta.set(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        consultaCompleta.set(true);
        Log.i("Local", "The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});

while (true) {
    // TODO: isso pode demorar a vida toda, considere adicionar um timeout
    if (consultaCompleta.get()) {
        dadosList.add(dados);
        break;
    }
}
```